# Помогите выбрать язык и инструменты для автоматизации веб приложения с 3d моделями (canvas)

Tags: автоматизация, регрессия

фронт Angular tree.js язык C#

Попробую описать, прошу прощение если сумбурно.

Это веб приложение со встроенным 3d сценой(canvas в DOM). Нужно будет отслеживать, изменение на сцене, после определенных шагов. Требуется произвести автоматизацию регресса. И сейчас почти каждый ручной тест заканчивается проверкой 3D объекта в canvas.
Не имею представления как подступиться к такому. С чего начать, как подобрать стек. Ибо это не обычный интернет магазин. И проверять изменения на 3D объектах, масштабировать да еще и 1000 сценариев, кажется не возможным.

Подскажите реализуемо ли это вообще?
Какой язык и библиотеки выбрать, в какую сторону смотреть?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.